# Append to Global List

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I just started learning WPF and C#. I have a global list that I want to append to on an event.

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<User> items = new List<User>();

    someEventHandler
           {
                items.Add(new User() { Name = "John", Age = 42 });
                listViewUsers.ItemsSource = items;
           }
}
```

However, this is only updated the first time the event fires, and not subsequent events. If I move

```
public List<User> items = new List<User>();
```

to someEventHandler, listViewUsers is will show only the latest update and not the previous record. How do I append to items?

Comment: is this only code? you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I would prefer to Bind everything in xaml via ViewModel, but to solve your problem, you should use `ObservableCollection` like below. It will automatically update the listview if item is added in collection:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<User> items = new ObservableCollection<User>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listViewUsers.ItemsSource = items;

        }

         someEventHandler
           {
                items.Add(new User() { Name = "John", Age = 42 });

           }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ObservableCollection`, `ObservableCollection` is a generic dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole collection is refreshed.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<User> items = new ObservableCollection<User>();

    someEventHandler
    {
         items.Add(new User() { Name = "John", Age = 42 });

    }
}
```

Other option is implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` *explicitly*  and notify change.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<User> items;
    public List<User> Items 
    {
         get {return items; }
         set {items=value;  onPropertyChanged(this, "Items") }; 
    }

    someEventHandler
    {
         items.Add(new User() { Name = "John", Age = 42 });
         onPropertyChanged(this, "Items") 
    }



    // Declare the PropertyChanged event
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // OnPropertyChanged will raise the PropertyChanged event passing the
    // source property that is being updated.
    private void onPropertyChanged(object sender, string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```